MySQL Workbench - Get data rows from model to db
I have made a model (EER / ERD) in MySQL workbench. With Database|Forward Engineering I got my data model into a local MySQL database. This has worked fine; I am seeing all the tables, constraints, indexes, ...
But I also have data rows in my model and I expected these to get inserted into the database tables, too. This has not happened.
I can synchronize model and db, but this always only affects the database structure it seems, not the data.
How do I get my data (table rows) from my model into my database?

You can export inserts from the Model by going to the File > Export > Forward Engineer SQL CREATE Script.
Check Generate Insert Statements for Tables.
Save the SQL file and then run the Script

Thank you. I didn' notice that option, because in my version it was a sub option for "Generate separate CREATE INDEX statements" (which of course makes no sense). I checked the option and it worked. Thank you.
